# write background service to call at particular time

Tags: android, service

I have writtern a service to run at an intervel of 2 hours. But I want them to be called like( 8am, 10 am, 12 pm etc). Not just every  2 hours from the time it had started.How to achieve it?

Comment: got to with this : https://medium.com/@RobertLevonyan/android-workmanager-manage-periodic-tasks-c13fa7744ebd

Answer (score 0):

you should write something like this :

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0); 

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);

alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: Does it support up to oreo and will get called even after 12pm

Comment: yes But  for Androids with API +26  you cannot run Service In the background